# Pointing a sub directory to another domain name

Tags: php, wordpress, dns, hosting

I have a domain name as **www.something.com** and which is hosted in a windows server.Now i have created a directory inside on it as **www.something.com/help** and need to point that to another server, I need to install a wordpress website on that. How can i point that.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a php redirect by creating an index.php file and placing the following in it:

```
<?php
header ('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
header("Location: http://www.anotherdomain.com");
?>
```

Comment: so can i give a DNS detais with the Location?

Comment: No, DNS is only available on the actual root domain. Not a sub directory. You'd have to either set up a header redirect like above, or put a frame in there.